# How to handle parameters in SQL PACKAGE?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table which has columns id, name and password.

I made also a SQL PACKAGE for that which looks like (I omitted Package header, since to emphasis my point more clear):

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY MEMBER
is
  FUNCTION createWith(v_id, v_name, v_password)
  return Number
  is

  BEGIN
    Insert into tbl_member(id, name, password)
    Values(v_id, v_name, v_password);
return SQL%ROWCOUNT ;
END createWith;
```

However, since name column is not necessary column(has no 'not null' option), I sometimes I pass only two parameters(id and password). As far as I know, if the numbers of parameter I sending and numbers of declared parameters in function do not match, it should be 'wrong type or number exception', but It works well.

The thing I wonder is how it can automatically handle empty parameter.
Is anyone who knows useful link or its logic, explain this.

//=============================================================

This is first addition

First of all, I guess my question was not clear enough.

So I going to try again.

step 0, make a table with no constrains and options.(also no default values)

step 1, this is the function header.

```
function creatWith(v_id in varchar2, v_name in varchar2, v_password in varchar2) return number;
```

step 2, I call this Package in java(it is web application based on Springframework. However, my company call this a 'solution', so I can not open source code). 
However, the method which mapped with this Function has only two parameters. like

```
public void insert(String id, String pw);
```

step 3, This is the point of question. It occurs an error or not? In my case, it works. But I do not know My company solution handle or Oracle DB automatically does this.

If Oracle does have, can I get some documents for this policy?

Comment: Well, you don't show your package spec or how it is called.  Do you have a DEFAULT attribute on the parameter?  Please show the other relevant code.

Comment: @OldProgrammer it is haed to explain, since I uses a solution of my company(It is made of java). I just wonder how Oracle DB handles those 'FUNCTION'.

Comment: Default parameters are explained in subsection _Default Values for IN Subprogram Parameters_ of [PL/SQL Subprograms](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e17126/subprograms.htm). That's part of Oracle's PL/SQL documentation.

Comment: The example code won't compile as there are no types specified for `v_id`, `v_name`, and `v_password`. Please edit your question and update the code it can be tested. In addition, even when types are specified for the parameters, I cannot reproduce the issue on Oracle 11.1. While editing the question please post code which compiles and executes without all the parameters given, and with no DEFAULT values specified for the parameters. Also, let us know what version of Oracle you're using. Thanks.

Comment: @BobJarvis I add header information and other situations. Would you check my question again? thanks

Comment: So let me try to paraphrase what you've said - a three-parameter PL/SQL routine is being called by a two-parameter Java routine. You're not allowed to see the Java code generated on your end, and you can't post it here. I think it's pretty clear that there is no way that anyone on StackOverflow can see any of the Java code either, and thus there's no way anyone can explain what the Java code is doing. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Oracle tries to use "NULL" values for empty parameters. Change the field to NOT NULL and it will start to return an error.

Try declaring a DEFAULT attribute, like:

```
FUNCTION createWith(
    v_id IN NUMBER, 
    v_name IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'empty', 
    v_password IN VARCHAR2)
```

With this, it will write 'empty' for the Name field when the parameter is empty.

Answer (score 0):

For Oracle Database, declare `DEFAULT` value in the function definition.

```
FUNCTION createWith(v_id IN NUMBER, 
  v_name IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT  'N.A.', 
  v_password IN VARCHAR2);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is not I wanted. It is the fact that it occurs an error if I put less parameters than declared in function, not how to set default value in function. Sorry for poor English. I made you confused.